# scattering matrix superccurent density of states

Tags: scattering, superconductivity

while studying scattering formula for the supercurrent ([Beenakker](http://arxiv.org/abs/cond-mat/9611162))
I encountered that the density of states for discrete and continuous spectrum can be simultaneously described by taking $\epsilon\ ->\ \epsilon + i\delta $ in the following formula:
$\rho(\epsilon) = -\frac{1}{\pi}Im\frac{d}{d\epsilon}\left\{lnDet\left[1 - S_{A}(\epsilon)S_{N}(\epsilon) \right] - \frac{1}{2}lnDet\left[S_{A}(\epsilon)S_{N}(\epsilon)\right]\right\}$.

I am wondering if one could argument this by referring to scattering theory and Green's function - eg. [Laszlo Szunyogh](http://newton.phy.bme.hu/~szunyogh/Elszerk/Kkr-slides.pdf).

Comment: did you find the answer of your question?